# Can physical shaking of a device be triggered in a Flutter integration test?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing

In my Flutter app I am using the plugin [shake](https://pub.dev/packages/shake) for detecting physical shaking of the device. Internally it uses the [sensors_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus) package, its `accelerometerEvents` to be precise.

Is it possible to mock this in a [Flutter Integration Test](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) somehow? I am looking for a way to do this programmatically.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Chech this out.

Click on the three dots.

[image]

Move down to Virtual Sensors

[image]

Play with x,y,z co-ordinates that changes accerlometer values.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Delwinn. I guess I was not precise enough in my question: What I was asking for was how to do this programmatically in an integration test (as introduced [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) for example).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help. Sorry